# Match last directory of URL with RE2 regex

Tags: regex, google-search-appliance, re2

For the standard GSA frontend, I'd like to filter on directory the result is in and I'd do this with entity recognition.

This regex matches exactly that: [^/]+(?=/[^/]+$) but it does not satisfy the RE2 syntax required by the GSA.

Is it possible to use the lookahead differently or does anyone know a valid RE2 substitute?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acc. to https://re2.googlecode.com/hg/doc/syntax.html, the lookaheads are not supported. Use just capturing groups:

`([^/]+)(?:/[^/]+$)`

Comment: Many thanks, however, this matches the last directory + everything after. Still can't seem to get it right.

Comment: Without examples, I doubt I can help further. If you test individual strings, I guess the current suggestion is OK?

Comment: @JasperQ BTW, now you can upvote, but I think it was you, right? :)